# How to control Python's += operator to update dictionary values in-place?

Tags: python

Consider the following:

```py
d = dict(a=(1,2))
d['a'] += (3,4)
assert d == {'a': (1, 2, 3, 4)}

# and yet
assert not hasattr(tuple, '__iadd__')
```

The way I parse this is that `(1, 2)` is first retrieved, then, since tuples are immutable, Python uses `__add__` to implement `__iadd__`, making `(1, 2) + (3, 4) == (1, 2, 3, 4)`. So far, nothing mysterious.

But then, somehow, this value is written "back" to `d['a']`!
The way I parse it, once `d['a']` gives forth the `(1, 2)`, both `d` and `'a'` are "forgotten". How does Python know "later", after computing the sum, that it should write back to `d['a']`?

I'd like to be able to "control" this behavior (see concrete use-case below). Since `d['a'] += (3, 4)` seems to resolve to `d['a'] = d['a'] + (3, 4)` my only hope seems to be do override the `__iadd__` or `__add__` of the **values** `d.__getitem__` outputs, which doesn't smell great.

#### Concrete use-case

My actual use case is I have [this](https://i2mint.github.io/dol/module_docs/dol/filesys.html#dol.filesys.Files) `MutableMapping` interface `Files` to a file system. For example:

```py
files = Files('~')
files['foo.txt'] = b'bar'  # writes b'bar' to the `~/foo.txt`
files['foo.txt']  # retrieves b'bar'
```

Now, `Files` does nothing explicit for this behavior:

```py
files['foo.txt'] += b'man'
assert files['foo.txt'] == b'barman'  # b'man' was appended to the contents!
```

The way it happens is that `b'bar'` was retrieved, `b'man'` was added, and the result was rewritten to the file.

But I'd like to have `files['foo.txt'] += b'man'` be *"open file, append, and close"*. How do I do that? One way is to have `files.__getitem__` return an object that will write back to the file, but then I don't have my "normal" `files['foo.txt']` as the contents of the file.

Comment: [_"...if `x` is an instance of a class with an `__iadd__()` method, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`. Otherwise, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered, as with the evaluation of `x + y`"_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) - because tuples don't have an `__iadd__` method, as you show, it becomes `dict['a'] = dict['a'].__add__((3, 4))`.

Comment: `d['a'] += (3,4)` is just `d['a'] = d['a'] + (3,4)`

Comment: Python evaluates `d['a'] + (3,4)` and assigns this new object (the new Tuple) to the value associated with the Dictionary key `['a']`.

Comment: @Guy That's true for tuples, which don't define `__iadd__`, but not for lists, which do.  For lists, the `+=` operator destructively modifies the list.  But none of this has anything to do with dictionaries.  The exact same behavior can be seen by just assigning to an ordinary variable.

Comment: @TomKarzes *But then, somehow, this value is written "back" to d['a']* the OP is wondering how the dictionary has the result of the action, which I commented on. `x += y` is a shortened form of `x = x + y`, including in lists (although `+=` might have unexpected results in case of a list).

Comment: @Guy They are not equivalent.  `+=` is intended to destructively modify the target, when possible.  `=` with `+` never does.  They can behave very differently. When the target is immutable, then they have no choice but to behave the same.  But in the case of lists, it's the exact opposite of what you said:  `+=` has the *expected* result of modifying the list.  The only reason it doesn't do the same with tuples is because it can't.  That's the entire reason why `__iadd__` exists: So the target object can be modified when possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that the open-append-close pattern will not be easy to add to your `Files` class. It was built upon the assumption that its  `__getitem__` method returns an immutable object (bytes). Changing that will require `__getitem__` to return a mutable object able to mimic all `str` methods, and able to be accepted by any operator accepting a string. So it will have to implement `__add__`, `__radd__`, `__mul__` and `__rmul__`.

As the object should know about its underlying file, it would then be possible to implement an `__iadd__` method on it.

Your problem is that you wanted to act on the containing class when you have to act on the contained one.

Comment: Yes -- this is the point of my question. Not merely "how does += work". The solution you proposing is also the only solution I was thinking of (except in my mind I only have to override `__iadd__` of `str`). I was hoping there was a less smelly way. Updated my post to make this clearer.